# Iterating a map from java into jsp

Tags: java, jsp, iterator

I am trying to iterate an arraylist on a java class file on to a jsp file to display output in table format.

JSP File:

```
<jsp:useBean id="mybean3" class="org.mypackage.process" scope="session" >  
  <jsp:setProperty name="mybean3" property="type" value="CARRIER DATA FILES" />
</jsp:useBean>

<table><tr><th>Header1</th> <th>Header2</th></tr>
<c:forEach items="${mybean3.values}" var="element3">
<tr>   <td><c:out value="${element3.DISTTT}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${element3.MESS}" /></td></tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

Java class file:

```
public void setType(String typecol) {
  mpp= new HashMap();
  abc = new ArrayList();
  this.typecol = typecol;
  for (int j=0;j<=5;j++){
    mpp.put("DISTTT",j);
    mpp.put("MESS",j);
    abc.add(mpp);   
  }
}

public ArrayList getValues(){
  Object ob;
  this.Values = abc;
  return Values;
}
```

Expecting O/P:

```
Header1 Header2
1          1 
2          2 
3          3
4          4
5          5
```

Current O/P:

```
Header1 Header2
5         5
5         5
5         5
5         5
5         5
```

Comment: [JSTL](http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/) is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you assign the `same` map to all rows. You have to assign a different one.

after

```
abc.add(mpp);
```

add

```
mpp = new HashMap();
```